# Can anyone remember a short TV series or movie from the 80s/90s about an alien girl who becomes popular on her first day in highschool

Tags: story-identification, aliens

All I really remember was that the girl was very fair with long blonde hair. She wore this pink outfit which was considered unique on her first day of high school. Other girls start copying her style the next day at school.

I can't remember much else other then the message about being yourself and not caring about what other people think.

I think the daughter of the family she was living with got a little jealous of the "alien" girls confidence etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenon:_Girl_of_the_21st_Century_(film) kind of matches (alien girl, blond hair, pink outfit), but she's specifically not popular.

Comment: *The Girl From Tomorrow* is another promising possibility, except that she has brown hair and she's not wearing pink on her first day.

Comment: If you think Australians are aliens, then that almost fits 'Grease'.

Comment: I thought of the Disney TV movie "Stepsister fromt he Planet Weird" which might be the one asked about.  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/StepsisterFromPlanetWeird#:~:text=Stepsister%20from%20Planet%20Weird%20is%20a%20Disney%20Channel,her%20little%20brother%20Trevor%20to%20be%20less%20annoying.

Comment: @Fuzzyboots  Xenon is a human girl.   The only thing alien about her is that she comes from a space station orbiting the Earth before being "grounded" on Earth.  The aliens she meets in the sequel could never pass as humans.

Answer (score 6):

The Disney TV move *Stepsister from Planet Weird* (June 17, 2000) has human girl Megan discover that her weird soon-to-be stepsister Ariel is actually a highly nonhuman alien who has taken human form.  My memories are not very vivid but I found evidence it might be the right one.

The synopsis here:

[TVTropes Summary](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/StepsisterFromPlanetWeird#:%7E:text=Stepsister%20from%20Planet%20Weird%20is%20a%20Disney%20Channel,her%20little%20brother%20Trevor%20to%20be%20less%20annoying.)

Says that Ariel becomes popular at their school.

And online photos of *Stepsister from Planet Weird* show that one of the two girls has blonde hair and wears a red and pink outfit.

Ariel is quoted as saying:

> "Every time I look at this horrid vehicle; the rubbery flesh, the flat face, the ghastly yellow hair that grows out of this hideous skull, I can only think I am grotesque."

[Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepsister_from_Planet_Weird)

So there is a fairly high chance that *Stepsister from Planet Weird* is the answer.